# Why is 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine, when run in Debug Mode only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

I have a C# source written by someone else, it has two configurations: Release and Debug both target Any CPU.

When I launch Release everything is great.  When I launch under Debug I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

All the things I tried:

- I installed the 64bit 11.2 Oracle driver administrator package with all default settings.
- The oracle bin folder is setup in my path.
- All users have correct security permissions for the oracle folder.
- I can run tnsping and other commands just fine from a cmd prompt.
- The regsvr32 OraOLEDB11.dll was run successfully.

---

For some reason, it works if I target specifically x64 in debug mode.  Why does it look for an x86 driver when run under Any CPU?  Again it works fine under Release in Any CPU.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903366/oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: Even if you target Any CPU it still sounds like your Debug Build tries to use the non-existent x86 db driver. Did you already try to explicitly targeting x64?

Comment: It works if I specifically target x64, but shouldn't it work with Any CPU?