# Adding Oracle connection string in SSIS .Error :The given path's format is not support

Tags: oracle, ssis, bids, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect to Oracle cliet in "Execute Sql task" of SSIS. I am able to add the connection and the Test Connection is succeeded.

But when I click on 'OK' to save it,it gives an error " The given path's format is not support"

The problem comes because of the Port Number.
If we remove the port number it works(it takes default one).

But I want to connect through a specific Port Number.Then its giving the error.

Please let me know if faced this problem..!!!!

Connection Manager

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to \u\rarediamond in the MSDN link, following is one of the workaround for the problem:
1. Error occurs due to there being ":" in the server name field before the port number.
2. Remove the ":" from the server name field and click OK.
3. Open properties of the saved connection.
4. Add the ":" back in before the port number. This should be able to resolve the issue.

Some discussion about this in the following [MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83d9eded-b201-4245-a01f-2c6e71cf3f94/adding-oracle-data-source-in-ssis-the-given-paths-format-is-not-support?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 64-bit version that may be the problem.

I was having the same issue, uninstalled 64-bit version, installed 32 bit version, and now everything is working fine

Comment: Also, you can take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903366/oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Answer (score 0):

Create new entry in tnsnames.ora file for your connection, then call it in your SSIS package