# OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on your local computer - oracle and windows 64 bit

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I have an issue with OleDBConnection in Visual Studio 2012. I reinstal my system from 32 Oracle to 64 Oracle with the same version of Windows 64. And i migrate my project ofcourse where it previously works.

I try to do all things in:
[OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903366/oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)
and also i install 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

but it dosen't helped..

Have you any idea how to resolve that problem?

Comment: Perhaps you did not make proper uninstall of 32bit Oracle Client, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: You can install 32bit and 64 bit Oracle Client at one machine, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: I have only 64 bit Oracle on my machine

Comment: Did you install the Oracle Client (e.g. Instant Client)? It is required by OLE DB provider.

Comment: I think yes. I can not install OLE DB provider without it.

Comment: You could, check `readme.htm` file. Maybe you mixed OLE DB 64 bit with existing 32 bit Oracle Client.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem and i fixed it by downloading "**ODAC122010Xcopy_x64**" from *http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html.*

follow these steps and try to run your application

Step 1: unzip **ODAC122010Xcopy_x64** in any folder on your computer.

Step 2: open command prompt as admin and run the ff commands.

Step 3: cd [ODAC122010Xcopy_x64 directory where you unzip it]

Step 4: INSTALL ALL "[DBHOME PATH]" [ORACLEHOMENAME] TRUE