# The ''OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, oracle

I need help.

So I am connecting in ASP.Net to a Oracle Database to get some information from a table, but the problem is that when I try to connect I get this error.

> 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

I have tried everything that I could.
I installed Oracle and I changed the plataform target, I even did something on CMD that was calling the dll or something.

My bin tho is different from the other, normally people have the bin in the path:

> oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\BIN

My bin is in this path:

> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin

As you can see my path (By the way) I know that Paths change for different people and stuff, but as you can see, my bin is inside a server folder and not a client_64 folder, I don't know if that may be an error, but I help with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903366/oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Where is your `OraOLEDB11.dll` file? This folder must be included in `PATH`